# Why would a reaction take place in this instance?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals

[image: exam question]

This makes little sense to me, both of the electron configurations are d6, and would presumably be low spin - therefore both reactants should be inert, and yet my notes suggest that an electron transfer would occur to form the products Co(II) and Ru(III). Surely this is a less stable arrangement?

Comment: You have false assumptions: just because something is d6 LS it doesn't mean inert.

Comment: Perhaps not, but surely the products, both with an unpaired electron are still less stable than the reactants. Perhaps the driving force is entropy?

Comment: Cobalt(II) is most certainly high-spin in this environment. Cobalt(III) is likely to be. However, I am at a loss for the answer …